# Nuget Reference error while installing googleanalyticssdk in UWP app

Tags: google-analytics, visual-studio-2015, nuget, windows-10, uwp

I have ported my windows 8.1 app to UWP app and now when  I try to install googleanalyticssdk into my app in visual studio 15 from nuget package manager I get the following error

Error:

> Failed to add reference to GoogleAnalytics.Core
>   I have tried many solutions such as uninstalling other versions etc etc but none of them seem to work for me. What might be the reasons please suggest.

Comment: Can you create a new blank UWP app and install the googleanalyticssdk  nuget package. If it works, then the problem lies with your app.

Comment: Can you share the detailed error logs?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps to install packages:

1. Right click the solution
2. Choose "**Manage Nuget Packages...**"
3. Search "**GoogleAnalyticsSDK**"
4. Install version **1.3.0**

If you still see such exception, please show us the Output from Package Manager, for example:
[image]

As karann mentioned, please also try the result of a blank UWP app, if it works, we need to focus on your existing project.